# Granting permissions to AppleScript script

Tags: applescript

I've a simple AppleScript that it's supposed to delete everything in the *Downloads* folder with exception of selected list of folders passed at the end.

```
tell application "Finder"
    delete (every item of "Downloads" of folder currentUser of folder "Users" of startup disk whose name is not in {"PreciousFolder"})
end tell
```

On save the AppleScript returns the following error:

[image: errormessage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to delete every item of the literal string `"Downloads"` which makes no sense. Add the `folder` specifier

```
tell application "Finder"
    delete (every item of folder "Downloads" of folder currentUser of folder "Users" of startup disk whose name is not in {"PreciousFolder"})
end tell
```

or shorter

```
tell application "Finder"
    delete (every item of (path to downloads folder) whose name is not in {"PreciousFolder"})
end tell
```

Comment: On the *folder specifier*, my intention is to delete files *and* folder from within the Downloads folder excluding *PreciousFolder* and it's contents. Do I need folder or file specifier in that case?

Comment: The `folder` specifier refers to the downloads folder not to its contents. `every item` considers both files and folders.